# Excel: Avoiding the use of IF formula - Insights

Tags: excel, performance, excel-formula

Supposed I have

```
=IF(A1>0, 100, 50)
```

which I can also write as

```
=(A1>0)*(100) + (A1<=0)*(50)
```

I am interested in their performances. So my question is, who will win in the racing tracks?

Anyway I can think of two drawbacks (not related to performance).

- The first drawback I had in mind is the latter form cannot return a text.
- The second drawback is error handling, supposed I have `=IFERROR(A1/B1, 0)`, I cannot substitute it with `=(B1=0)*(0) + (B1<>0)*(A1/B1)` which will still return a `DIV/0` error.

In terms of performance drawback, I have one tickling my mind:

- The latter form computes both `IfTrue` part and `IfFalse` part, which seems to be a drawback unless `IF` also compute both parts which I'm not sure about.

In terms of performance benefits:

- The `IF` formula needs to consider for number or text outcome. The latter form simply return a number which makes it more light weighted.

Thanks!

Comment: IF will be faster: it short-circuits and requires many less operations ( data accesses and calculations)

Comment: `IF` ignores one of the calculations depending on whether the tested value is true. In the other solution, all calculations are mandatory. Thus `IF` is faster.